# Calculate put price with Black-Scholes and one discrete dividend

Tags: options, option-pricing, european, discrete-dividends

I try to solve this exercise:

a) Calclculate the price of a 3-month European put option on a non-dividend-paying stock with a strike price of 45 when the current stock price is 40, the risk-free interest rate is 5% per annum, and the volatility is 40% per annum.

b) What dierence does it make to the option price if a dividend of 1.50 is expected in 2 months?

While I can solve a) im not able to solve b). My solution for a) is:
$T=\frac{1}{4}, K=45, S_0=40,r=0.05,\sigma=0.4$ leads to $$d_{+}=\frac{\ln\left( \frac{S_0}{K}\right)-(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T}{\sigma \sqrt T}=-0.7514$$ and $$d_{-}=-0.9514.$$ Hence the put option price is given by $$P_0=-S_0N(-d_{+})+Ke^{-rT}N(-d_{-})=5.9042.$$

Can anybody explain how b) works?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to calculate the annual dividend yield implied by that. 
$Div_{yield}=\delta=1.5/40$ and then replace the $r$ on $d_+$ by $r-\delta$.

A cleaner way would be to compute it using a binomial tree.

Comment: And I use the exact same formula for $P_0$? I don't use $-S_0 e^{-\delta T}$ instead of $-S_0$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but with "Yes, you are right." you mean that I have to use $-S_0e^{-\delta T}$?

Comment: Yes you have to use $-S_0e^{-\delta T}$